# Set height of div after Jquery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that loads content into a div with Jquery. I'm trying to add to my function, the ability to set the height of the div to fit the content that I'm loading to it. I've tried several variations of the height() function and I've looked around at other people's code, but t I don't think I really  understand how to incorporate that to my particular. Here's the function. It also has some code to update the URL. contentarea is the div where everything gets loaded and the div that needs resizing.

```
    //Jquery loader
    function getHash() {
        return window.location.hash
    }

    $("a").on("click", function (e) {
        var page = this.href.replace("#", "") + ".html",
        hash = $(this).prop("hash");

        $('#contentarea').load(page, function () {
            if (page.match("home.html")) {
                history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
            } 
            else {
                location.hash = hash;
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: I updated the code with your help, but it's not really working. I figured I would add a div called content inside of contentarea, and use a callback function. What am I doing wrong?

'

```
$('#contentarea').load(page, function () {
    if (page.match("home.html")) {
        history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
    } else {
        location.hash = hash;
    }
}, function () {
    $('#contentarea').height($('#content').height());
});
```

'

Comment: Don't put a link to an external website, put all your relevant code to reproduce the problem in the question itself. Use jsFiddle if needed.

Comment: There's nothing working out `height` in the code you provided.

Comment: Ok I made the changes to the question. Also, I didn't put any code regarding height, because like i said, I really didn't know how to code it and incorporate it to my function. That's where I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the .load() provide a callback when the function is completed

[JQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#contentarea').load(page, function(){},function(){})
```

The second function is called when the funciton load is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call callback function after content is loaded.

```
jQuery('#contentarea').load('externalpage.php', function() {
   jQuery('#contentarea').height(jQuery('#content').height());
});
```

Comment: What does the #content stand for? My #contentarea div doesn't have any divs inside of it.

Comment: its a div that contain the whole loaded page.